# How to use highstock with django

Tags: javascript, python, django

I can't use Highstock correctly.

I'm trying to display a candlestick chart with using django and highstock.

My code transfers some ohlcv data from django backend to HTML frontend in JSON format.
And Highstock displays chart but not correctly.

I read highstock official documents but I can't understand many options because I'm a newbie(not only python and javascript even programming).

Please look at my code and a result.

I'd like to teach me.

## models.py

```
from django.db import models

class OandaChartData(models.Model):

    exchange_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pair = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    open_time = models.DateTimeField()
    open_value = models.FloatField()
    high_value = models.FloatField()
    low_value = models.FloatField()
    close_value = models.FloatField()
    volume = models.FloatField()
    write_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import OandaChartData
from django.core import serializers
import json
from datetime import timezone

def highstock_view(request):

    record_list = []

    records = OandaChartData.objects.all().order_by("id")[0:43200]

    for record in records:

        open_time = record.open_time.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp() * 1000
        open_value = record.open_value
        high_value = record.high_value
        low_value = record.low_value
        close_value = record.close_value
        volume = record.volume

        record_list_tmp = [open_time, open_value, high_value, low_value, close_value, volume]

        record_list.append(record_list_tmp)

    record_json = json.dumps(record_list)

    return render(request, 'scraping/highstock_view.html', {'record_json':record_json})
```

## HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>HighStockView</title>
</head>
<body>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>

    <div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>

    <script>

    let data = {{record_json|safe}},
        ohlc = [],
        volume = [],
        datalength = data.length,

        groupingUnits = [[
            'minutes',
            [1, 5, 15, 30]
        ], [
            'hours',
            [1, 2, 4, 12]
        ], [
            'month',
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
        ]],

        i = 0;

    for (i ; i < datalength ; i += 1) {
        ohlc.push([
            data[i][0],
            data[i][1],
            data[i][2],
            data[i][3],
            data[i][4],
        ]);

        volume.push([
            data[i][0],
            data[i][5],
        ]);
    }

        // create the chart
        Highcharts.stockChart('container', {


            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 1
            },

            title: {
                text: 'OANDA USD/JPY'
            },

            yAxis: [{
                labels: {
                    align: 'right',
                    x: -3
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'OHLC'
                },
                height: '60%',
                lineWidth: 2,
                resize: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }, {
                labels: {
                    align: 'right',
                    x: -3
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Volume'
                },
                top: '65%',
                height: '35%',
                offset: 0,
                lineWidth: 2
            }],

            tooltip: {
                split: true
            },

            series: [{
                type: 'candlestick',
                name: 'USD/JPY',
                data: ohlc,
                dataGrouping: {
                    units: groupingUnits
                }
            }, {
                type: 'column',
                name: 'Volume',
                data: volume,
                yAxis: 1,
                dataGrouping: {
                    units: groupingUnits
                }
            }]
        });
</script>

{{ record_json }}
```

[This is screenshot of above HTML page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPM5o.png)

JSON data is a 1-minute data for 1 month.

I want to display a 1-minute chart but above HTML seems to display a 1-month chart(But 2 candlesticks(two months period ?) are displayed.)

And above HTML has some grey out button.

note: The raw text following the chart in the HTML is to confirm data transferring correctly.

Please help me.

db.sqlite3 file is in the following link.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bFun10rcbOjmqSTv45QfkL26pfMpvzZZ/view?usp=sharing

And sample.txt that received by frontend HTML is in the following link.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KXASJDunrKkVHmn5Y9u5R-f1x_ZH5lrn/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi @Pierogi, Could you provide me with an example of your data so that I could reproduce the problem?

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, Thank you for your reply.
I attached db.sqlite3 file in my django and sample.txt received by HTML frontend.
Is this OK?

Comment: That issue is caused by `dataGrouping` - please check the result without it: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/r7wk3vcz/ The performance is not very good, so it is recommended to use `dataGrouping`, but maybe with different group units? http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/c6wxga2p/ You can also consider lazy-loading: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/lazy-loading/

Comment: Thank you for your teaching. I'll learn dataGrouping.
And Creating lazy-loading difficult for me, but I'll try it.